# Is there a shortcut for Resharper to allow it to execute all green and yellow suggestions?

Tags: resharper

I have some code where there are a series of "green" light bulb suggestions that Resharper is telling me I could use an object initializer for.

I see this kind of thing in legacy code **all** the time, where there's some code pattern repeated over and over again where Resharper knows how to clean it up automatically for me, but I have to go to each item and use a shortcut key on each item to execute the refactoring.

What I want to know: Is there a way (shortcut/whatever) to tell Resharper that I want it to go ahead and execute all of these "light bulb" refactorings, or at least all the ones where there's only one suggestion. I can understand if there are two suggestions it would know which one to use.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Currently there's no way to auto-apply quick-fixes. There was a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7284590/resharper-find-and-fix-all-issues-at-once) recently with answers providing a bit more details.

One thing that I'd suggest right now is to use [Find similar issues](http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/whatsnew/index.html#FindSimilar) introduced in ReSharper 6: this will at least make sure that you can access all code positions where ReSharper highlights this particular inspection, and apply the quick-fix with a tedious repeat of **Enter** (open the file with the detected issue and select the highlighted piece of code) - **Esc** (navigate from "Inspection Results" tool window to the code editor) - **Alt+Enter** (open the quick-fix menu) - **Enter** (apply the quick-fix) - **Alt+R,W,I** (return to Inspection Results)

Answer (score 2):

There's silent clean-up which can be mapped to a [config profile](http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/webhelp/Code_Cleanup__Creating_Custom_Profiles.html). This will action all of of the preferences defined in the profile on `ctrl-e,f` (VS scheme).

By default I don't think it has a profile assigned so you have to set one first in the options. Also the shortcut varies depending on whether you have VS shortcuts or R shortcuts.

Comment: Yeah I actually tried that but I couldn't find a setting on the profile for using an object initializer, which is what I was trying to refactor.

Comment: I believe it's limited to the options in the profile unfortunately.